# OS determining input for the kernel or for some user program

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

How does a operating system recognise user input as a command or an input to some program? Example:

> chmod

It is a command to change the access rights but when I run a program, say some program asking for input then how is that input specifically designated to that program?

From my point of view when we enter something on the command line screen it first goes to some buffer and then it needs some kind of user/system mode to transfer that input to the running program or to the kernel. But how does OS distinguishes between all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It various with OS, and with how the UI is constructed.  Most multi-window systems have some notion of *focus*, which where keyboard, mouse, etc inputs are delivered to.   In a terminal window of a UNIX-based system, the rules are well described in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/.  In the absence of job control, as the program below demonstrates, programs compete for the tty input; and depending upon the line-editing mode of the tty (stty), you can get different outcomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char buf[100];
    fork();
    int n;
    while ((n = read(0, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
        printf("%d: %*s\n", getpid(), n, buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```